# Call Rake Method inside of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake-task

I have a helper method (create_employee) inside of a Rake task that I would like to use inside a Rails controller.

```
lib/taks/billing.rb

require 'rake'

task :billing => :environment do
  //logic in task
end

create_employee args1
  //logic to create new employee
end
```

How can I call this method within a Rails Controller?

Answer (score 0):

`system "RAILS_ENV="+Rails.env+" rake foo:bar"`

Comment: So, how exactly would you use it inside controller?

Comment: I might suggest string interpolation here as well as prepending `bundle exec` so do:
`system "RAILS_ENV=#{Rails.env} bundle exec rake foo:bar"`

@AndreyDeineko He's literally given you the exact command here.  `system` runs shell commands as you would on the terminal command line.